# How to convert ArrayList<HashMap<K,V>> to List<V> in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I would like to convert an `ArrayList` of `HashMap` into a `List` of the maps `values`.

The `values` within the map are of a custom class `MapValuesClass`. The `key` is not important and I can lose it.

The `attempt1` recommended below loses the groupings of the map entries. How can I do something similar to `flatmap` but have each item in the list of type `MapValuesClass`? See desired result below.

##### Attempt 1

`val attempt1 = arrayListOfHashmaps.flatMap { it.values }`

[image]

##### Desired Result

[image]

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val arrayListOfHashmaps = arrayListOf(
            hashMapOf(
                "string" to "value1",
                "Int" to 1,
                "Double" to 1.0
            ),
            hashMapOf(
                "string" to "value2",
                "Int" to 2,
                "Double" to 2.0
            ),
            hashMapOf(
                "string" to "value3",
                "Int" to 3,
                "Double" to 3.0
            ),
        )

        val attempt1 = arrayListOfHashmaps.flatMap { it.values }
        
        val desired = listOf(
            MapValuesClass("value1", 1, 1.0),
            MapValuesClass("value2", 2, 2.0),
            MapValuesClass("value3", 3, 3.0),
        )
    }


    data class MapValuesClass(
        val string: String,
        val integer: Int,
        val double: Double,
    )
```

Comment: `list.flatMap { it.values }`

Comment: I am starting with an `ArrayList`, not a `Map`. Therefore I can't call `map.values`

Comment: You can if you do it like I wrote above. Convert the values of each list entry.

Comment: @Jorn This still isn't working for me. I have updated question to illustrate.

Comment: You are apparently expecting some custom class `MapValuesClass`. Update your question to show what you actually need.

Comment: @Jorn updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list with map as below:

```
val desired = arrayListOfHashmaps.map{ MapValuesClass(it["string"] as String,
                it["Int"] as Int,
                it["Double"] as Double)}
```

But if needed, you have to do some exception handling based on your data to avoid any conversion error